# Probability of two fixed-length line segments intersecting within a circular domain

Tags: calculus, probability, geometry, geometric-probability

Imagine placing a line segment *P* of length *a* on the *XY* plane such that its middle is at the origin, but its orientation is random (i.e. random angle). Then suppose you placed another line segment *Q* of length *b* (which is less than or equal to *a*) such that its centre was randomly chosen within a radius *(a+b)/2* from the origin, but its orientation was also random. What would the probability of these two line segments intersecting be?

I suspect there may be an integral over the circular surface to be done here, but am not quite sure what to do! Any help much appreciated. Thank you.

[image: This image shows you what I mean. Here the two line segments don't intersect.]

Comment: The placement protocol for a segment doesn't appear to be well defined. Assume you choose the center uniformly inside the circle, then not all orientations are necessarily possible; choose the orientation first, then not all center or endpoint positions are possible...

Comment: Suggested way of performing  the experiment: Select a random location then a random direction and throw away the segment if it sticks out from the circle. Do this until you have found two fitting segments. What is the probability that these segments intersect.

Comment: Thanks guys you've really made me think about the problem which is really important. I've changed the problem definition quite a bit such that I think it is clearer.

Comment: From your drawing they will never intersect.  Please review your question carefully.

Comment: Apologies the drawing was misleading. The second segment Q is placed **anywhere** within the circle of radius _(a + b)/2_. The drawing shows a particular case where they don't intersect.

Comment: @A.Bhalerao: The question of how to select a random chord in a circle (which is not exactly the question of how the second segment is positioned here, but is clearly related) is the "Bertrand paradox": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability) .  Reading about that might help clarify your thinking or be interesting to you.

Answer (score 0):

Let the segment of length $a$ be called $A$, and that with length $b$ be called $B$.
Now, whatever the orientation of $A$, the probability of intersection shall be the same due to circular symmetry. So just fix $A$ to lie on the $x-axis$.

For $B$, let its center be at $(r,\theta)$ so that its equation is $(x-rcos\theta)^2 + (y-rsin\theta)^2 = b^2/4$. This will intersect the X axis when 
$(x-rcos\theta)^2 = b^2/4 - (rsin\theta)^2$. This gives the conditions $-b/4<rsin\theta<b/4$ and $rcos\theta + \sqrt{(b^2/4-(rsin\theta)^2)}<a/2$ or $rcos\theta - \sqrt{(b^2/4-(rsin\theta)^2)}>-a/2$. Further, the itegral will have to be multiplied by a factor $\alpha/2\pi$ where $\alpha = 2rsin\theta/b$.

This will be a messy thing to integrate, but it can be done.